# Access to facebook data

Tags: database, facebook

I want to access facebook's database.
I want to have some SQL-like access, let's like this:

```
"select name from facebook-big-database-table where location='France' and city='Paris' and age
between 30 and 40;"
```

But, it need not to be SQL, PHP or JAVA would also be nice to use to me.

Does anybody know where to start?
To be honest, I got a little bit lost in all the tutorials Facebook offers.
Is it the so called "Connect" program which offers me what I want or something different?

Comment: Ask Mark Zuckerberg, maybe he'll give you db permissions.

Comment: What's with all the down votes?  Even if what Alex is asking can't be done, the question is not inappropriate and having a straightforward answer like "it can't be done" may be exactly what a future individual needs to read.  Sympathy up vote.

Comment: Agreed. It's a good, simple question which deserves an answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just put a *very* witty comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does have a bunch of API's, one of which actually looks like SQL. They call it FQL. Check it out [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL). Maybe it can help you some part of the way at least.

Note that it won't give you raw access to the underlying tables. But still, better than nothing I guess.

Comment: Thank you - I was exactly searching this FQL, but did not know how they call it.

Comment: Note: "On August 17, 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried." See [FQL Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) and [FQL Overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/).

Answer (score 2):

Facebook isn't going to let you mine their database in that way. Not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to access facebook's database. The most you'd be able to do is to get information of users who previously have consented your application to access their data.

Therefore answering your question, what you want can't be done, period.